# Is my USB dead or just really hard to get into?

Tags: usb, usb-storage

Using my sandisk cruzer glide (8GB), I was putting windows 7 onto the usb to install onto another PC. When halfway through, it said "This drive is read-only". I got confused, but then I went to computer and the I couldn't even open the drive. I checked it in diskmgmt.msc and it said "read only". Afterwards I checked the USB on gparted live and it turns out the partiton has changed to HFS+. After trying to rewrite the partition table (and it failing because of read-only) I tried using diskpart next

apparently I just had to do `attributes disk clear readonly` (with disk being the USB) but that did nothing. When doing `attributes disk` it still said `Current read-only state: Yes` even though below it says `Read Only: No`. I've also tried chipgenius, and only got this far:

```
Device Name: ++USB Mass Storage Device(SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB Device)

PnP Device ID: VID = 0781 PID = 5567
Serial Number: 2005485881119AF2F91A
Revision: 1.20

Device Type: Standard USB device - 

Chip Vendor: (No match record)
Chip Part-Number: (No match record)

Product Vendor: SanDisk
Product Model: Cruzer Blade

Tools on Web: (N/A)
```

What should I do now? I am completely out of ideas. (I have also tried BOOTICE, but that did nothing too)

Comment: Try [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) from the SD Association. If that won't do it, bin it. Sounds like the firmware has triggered read-only mode, which is pretty much irreversible.

Comment: windows+r   regedit

go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies

go to write protection and set value to 0

If it not there you could create it with a new DWORD naming it WriteProtect and value to 0..

like any changes to the reg, make a backup first

Answer (score -1):

Forcing a hardware re-scan sometimes resolves problems with USB.
You can tryrestarting the computer or plugging onto another USB port which would force hardware detection to pick it up again

You can also use diskpart and execute 
ATT DIS CLEAR READONLY

There is a collection of different methods and tools in this:
http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/54---how-to-fix-write-protected-disks

short of this, I am afraid you will have to buy a new one.